# How to reduce query time for stackexchange api?

Tags: r, stackexchange-api

I try to collect for a list of users the questions.

So I prepared this command lines:

```
library(stackr)
dft <- data.frame()
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
     questions <- stack_users(df$userid[j], "questions", num_pages=1000000, pagesize=100, filter="withbody")                
    for (s in 1:nrow(questions)){
      dft <- rbind(dft, data.frame(
        tags               = ifelse(is.null(questions$tags[s])               , NA, questions$tags[s]),
        is_answered        = ifelse(is.null(questions$is_answered[s])        , NA, questions$is_answered[s]),
        view_count         = ifelse(is.null(questions$view_count[s])         , NA, questions$view_count[s]),
        accepted_answer_id = ifelse(is.null(questions$accepted_answer_id[s]) , NA, questions$accepted_answer_id[s]),
        answer_count       = ifelse(is.null(questions$answer_count[s])       , NA, questions$answer_count[s]),
        score              = ifelse(is.null(questions$score[s])              , NA, questions$score[s]),
        last_activity_date = ifelse(is.null(questions$last_activity_date[s]) , NA, questions$last_activity_date[s]),
        creation_date      = ifelse(is.null(questions$creation_date[s])      , NA, questions$creation_date[s]),
        last_edit_date     = ifelse(is.null(questions$last_edit_date[s])     , NA, questions$last_edit_date[s]),
        question_id        = ifelse(is.null(questions$question_id[s])        , NA, questions$question_id[s]),
        link               = ifelse(is.null(questions$link[s])               , NA, questions$link[s]),
        title              = ifelse(is.null(questions$title[s])              , NA, questions$title[s]),
        body               = ifelse(is.null(questions$body[s])               , NA, questions$body[s]),
        owner_reputation   = ifelse(is.null(questions$owner_reputation[s])   , NA, questions$owner_reputation[s]),
        owner_user_id      = ifelse(is.null(questions$owner_user_id[s])      , NA, questions$owner_user_id[s]),
        owner_user_type    = ifelse(is.null(questions$owner_user_type[s])    , NA, questions$owner_user_type[s]),
        owner_accept_rate  = ifelse(is.null(questions$owner_accept_rate[s])  , NA, questions$owner_accept_rate[s]),
        owner_link         = ifelse(is.null(questions$owner_link[s])         , NA, questions$owner_link[s])
      ))

    }       

}
```

However it takes to much time to collect a list of different user ids. Is there any way to reduce the execution time or update to code I could make?

Comment: Just my opinion, but that huge single heavily-nested `rbind`-from-heck is waaaaaaaay too big and hard to read. But some pointers: if (1) `questions` is a `data.frame` with 1 or more rows; and (2) each column is "simple" meaning a vector and not some `tidy`-ish list of compound elements; then you will never have a `NULL` in there, so you should be able to remove the vast majority of conditional code.

Comment: Second, don't iteratively add to a frame, it performs *horribly*. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207, then try something like `qs <- lapply(df$userid, stack_users, "questions", num_pages=1000000, pagesize=100, filter="withbody"))` then `do.call(rbind.data.frame, qs)`.

Comment: @r2evans for (1) yes it is a dataframe with one or more rows

Comment: Also, you need to confirm what packages you are using. There are multiple `stackr`s on github, but I found one that has `stack_users`, is it https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr? Please make this question reproducible by listing all non-base R packages and including a sample of the data used, perhaps `dput(head(df))`. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Have you tried replacing all of this code with `stack_users(df$userid, "questions", ...)`? Or even `do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(split(df$userid, floor((seq_along(df$userid)-1)/3)), stack_users, "questions", ...))`.

Comment: @r2evans there a possibility one user id does not have info. So I receive an error and that's why I use NA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer since I'm not fluent in `r`:

Are you trying to get the list of questions for a given set of users?

If so,

```
for (j in 1:nrow(df)) {
    questions <- stack_users(df$userid[j]...
```

is a poor way to do it.

Refer to [the API's `/users/{ids}/questions` doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users):

> (The) {ids} (parameter) can **contain up to 100 semicolon delimited ids**. To find ids programmatically look for user_id on user or shallow_user objects.

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

So instead of something that evaluates to `stack_users(1,...` (one id)

**Group the ids in batches of 100 for that function**.  Something like:

```
stack_users(c(1,2,3,4,5,...),...
```

<sup>(But remember I'm not an `r` coder.)</sup>

Comment: The approach is correct, and the [source code for the function](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr/blob/master/R/stack_users.R#L6) confirms that it accepts one or more, but that does not resemble valid R code. Your could should read something like `stack_users(c(1,2,3,4,5,...),...)`, where the `c(...)` encapsulates its contents into a vector that is collectively passed as the first argument. And R uses commas, not semi-colons.

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans.  incorporated into answer. I don't yet know the correct syntax for `c()`, but the API requires semicolons.  I guess the library handles that?

Comment: @BrockAdams thank you I tried this but it it possible some users don't have questions. So there is any content and possible I receive this error: `Error in stack_parse(req) : Error 404: no method found with this name` possible with a try catch I could prevent it ?

Comment: @Stiar, open a new question for that if you need to, but it doesn't make sense.  The API doesn't 404 if the user has no questions.  ... Here's [a user with no questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/52/).  ... Here [the API gives valid, but empty results](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/52/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow), just like it should. There is no 404